# How can you change the default formatting for helpers in MVC Razor views?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with Resharper.

When I use `Format Document` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) on my views, my helpers are indented strangely:

```
<div>
    Hello @DisplayText("world!")
</div>

@helper DisplayText(string text)
    {
        <b>@text</b>
}
```

How can I configure Visual Studio or Resharper to format the helper like this:

```
@helper DisplayText(string text)
{
    <b>@text</b>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this issue to Microsoft and it was accepted as a bug.

This behavior no longer happens in 15.7.0.

Answer (score -1):

Open view in Visual Studio 2017/2015/2013, and just press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to format your code (c# or Razor or HTML)

Comment: My question: "When I start my car, it makes a rattling noise. How do I fix it?"  Your answer: "Turn the ignition key to start your car."